# Procedure or technique or reasoning to get $2+4h$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, education

I have solved for my students of an high school this simple trigonometric equation:

$$\tan(\pi+6x)=-\tan(2x)\tag 1$$

The $(1)$ is equivalent to (I remember also that $\tan(\alpha)=\tan(\mathbb Z\pi+\alpha)$)

$$\tan(\pi+6x)=\tan(-2x)\tag 2 \iff x=\frac{\pi}{8}k^*, \quad k^*=k-1\in\Bbb Z$$

But the solution of the textbook is $x=k\pi/8$ with $k\neq 4h+2$.

> How can I find the value $\color{red}{4h+2}$?

If I calculate the domain I will have

$$\begin{cases}
 x \neq -\dfrac \pi{12}+\Bbb Z\dfrac \pi{6}\\[0.5em] \tag 3
 x\neq \dfrac \pi4+\Bbb Z\dfrac\pi2
\end{cases}$$

I have done the tests and the condition $4h+2$ is equivalent to $(3)$. Just a curiosity looking the 2nd negation of the $(3)$ I have the denominator $4$ and $2$.

Comment: We can write : $tan(\pi+6x)=tan(2k\pi-2x)\Rightarrow x=(2k-1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{8}$

Comment: @Sebastinao, please see my answer (with the constrain   k≠ 4h+2).

Comment: @sirous Hi, yes you have right. But how I found $k≠ 4h+2$?

Comment: @BrightStar Yes I have seen but there are many mistakes :-) in $\LaTeX$ :-( +1 for your answer.

Comment: It is probably $k\neq(4h+2)$ for general solution $x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}8$.

Comment: @sirous Yes, I have misprint the value of $k$, and thank you also to mathlove user.

Comment: @Downvoter: What is the reason of the downvote?

Comment: @Sebastiano, As I can see it is upvote!

Comment: @sirous Hi, kindest...see my profile (you can see +2 and -1 on the question). I have also my loved hater(s) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constrains come from the domain of tangent function. The domains of $\tan x$ excludes $k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$,  there  are constrains placed on $\tan2x$ and $\tan 6x$, where $k,m,n,h \in \mathbb Z$.

For $\tan 2x$, we have $$2x \neq m\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$$ with $x\neq  \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}$.

For $\tan  6x$, we have $$6x \neq n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$$ with  $x \neq  \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{12}$.

Or

$k\pi/8 \neq\frac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}$, $k\neq  2(2m+1) =4m+2, \quad (A)$;

$k\pi/8 \neq\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{12}$, $k\neq  \frac{2(2m+1)}{3} \equiv \frac{4m+2}{3} \quad (B)$.

If (A) is satisfied, so is (B).

Therefore, The solutions are

$$x = \frac{k\pi}{8}$$ with $k\neq 4h+2$

Comment: For trig functions, use a backslash, eg  ``$\sin x$`` comes out as $\sin x$.

Comment: Excuse me for my delay...thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

For $x=\pi+\frac{\pi}8$:

LHS: $\tan [\pi +6(\pi+\frac{\pi}8)]=\tan(\pi+\frac{3\pi}4)=\tan(-\frac{\pi}4)$

RHS: $-2(\pi+\frac{\pi}8)=- \frac{\pi}4$

So general form of solution can be:

$x=(2m+1)\pi+\frac{\pi}8=[8(2m+1)+1]\frac{\pi}8$

Let $2(2m+1)=h$, we have:

$x=(4h+1)\frac{\pi}8$

So $k=(4h+1)\neq(4h+2)$

Comment: Very nice also your answer. +1

Comment: Hi, I have not understood the reason of this downvote on my question.